# Python import cv2 runs forever

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

My OS is ubuntu 16.04, Python 2

I installed opencv followed this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/), the only difference is that I am not using an virtual python environment.

After installation is done, there is a cv2.so file in both /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

However, when I try to import cv2 in Python, it will keep importing forever like this

[image]

Any ideas?

Update: After waiting for a loooooong time, cv2 was imported successfully

Comment: You could try out by creating a `script.py` file and place the import and run it with: `python script.py` in the terminal

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, thanks for answering, I tried this solution, but it the problem keeps unchanged